# CMAltitude always returns as nil when run outside loop in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, cmmotionmanager

Recently I've been writing a game that requires the Pitch of the device in order to move the character. However, to make it so the user doesn't have to play the game with the device fixed in one starting point every time, every time the user presses play I want the app to acquire the initial tilt. This does not work however, I've added a test button that is suppose to run the code:

```
  func recordTilt() {
  InitialTilt = MovementManager.deviceMotion?.attitude
  print(InitialTilt)
  }
```

The problem with this is that whenever the button is pressed, InitialTilt will return nil. However, if InitialTilt is run in a the Loop it will return a value every time.

Movement Manager Loop:

```
func setup() {
  MovementManager = CMMotionManager()
  MovementManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1
  MovementManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()
  InintialTilt = Movementmanager.deviceMotion?.attitude

}

func movementManaging() {
//...
InintialTilt = Movementmanager.deviceMotion?.attitude // returns every
time
//...
}

func update() {
movementManaging()
}
```

Can someone please help explain to me why the (InintialTilt = Movementmanager.deviceMotion?.attitude) only returns a value while it is in a loop.

(Note: The movementManaging is basically a loop that controls the player's movements, if one were to expand the ...'s all they would get are a bunch of if methods that keep the player on screen. +  InintialTilt = Movementmanager.deviceMotion?.attitude)

Comment: Where is there a loop? It looks like three functions ...

Comment: sorry for not clarifying, setup just sets up the movement manager (Not a loop), movementManaging has code for player movement, and it is run in the main update loop.